# Who is the winner?

Tags: logical-deduction

Dr. Doom invited a group of puzzle freaks in a party which was directed for having puzzle oriented games. At night, he introduced the guests with a 'unique riddle'. A prize was offered for the one who solved it first.

The guests included six people named Tom Paul, Fox Obama, Jeremy Reener, Alex Murphy, Prim Pastor, and Ellen Page. The winner for the 'unique riddle' contest was to be announce after the dinner. The winner would get ‘Ultimate Riddler’ as their new title, the initials being ‘UR’. So Dr. Doom stood up and started the announcement:

'Okay now everybody!'

'The winner of…'

'The Hardest Riddle Ever Event'

But before he could complete, the light went out and his voice was not heard without the mic by anyone. But they already knew who the winner was. Can you analyze the name of the winner?

(Everyone did the riddle seperately so they didn’t cheat, so they didn’t know the winner before the announcement)
This is adapted from another riddle on the other end of the internet.

Comment: Tag seems wrong.

Comment: I've seen this across many sites before, can you please cite which one you got it from?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Going off of Riley's answer, the full answer is:

> Fox Obama

Because:

> The first letters of the previous statements spelled "ONE", "TWO", and "THREE", so he was about to say something with first letters "FOUR". "Fox Obama Ultimate Riddler" fits the bill.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Pretty sure it’s someone who got it wrong, either in their head or posted it, because YeetKid got a downvote too.

Answer (score 13):

The answer is

> Fox Obama

If you look at what he says

> Okay now everybody! (taking first letters gives "one")

Then

> The winner of ("two")

Finally

> 'The Hardest Riddle Ever Event' ("three")

Therefore, the final thing should be

> four. Since the winner is titled UR, this makes up the last two letters of "four" so the first two letters are "FO" pointing to Fox Obama

Comment: Seems like you posted first than @Austin Weaver.

Comment: @maounkhan I posted 3 minutes before him.

Comment: @AustinWeaver not from my perspective? idk maybe theres some weird laag time thing lol

Comment: @Austin Weaver for me it shows that you posted 3 minutes after him

Comment: @maounkhan If you hover over the "answered __ minutes ago", it will tell you the exact time the answer was posted. My answer was at 00:23:20, YeetKid's was at 00:26:06.

Comment: Well, I can’t do that know, @AustinWeaver, I’m on mobile.

Comment: I can confirm that from my perspective it shows Austin Weaver answered first

Comment: OK, is it fine if I change it?

Comment: @YeetKid when you say "not from my perspective", do you mean that you did not see Austin Weaver's answer, or do you mean that it displays your answer as being answered at an earlier time? Because if you just didn't see his answer, that's something else entirely.

Comment: @Riley mine is showing that YeetKid answered first by three minutes but I cannot confirm by the hovering thing. Did you use the hovering method or just saw the minute like this. If you just saw it like that, I’m just gonna have to keep it like this because is what I saw go first on my side.

Comment: @maounkhan Via hovering method and what it normally displays. Both show that Austin Weaver answered first. As of right now, for YeetKid it says 56 mins ago. For Austin Weaver it says 59 mins ago. Maybe you're confused because of "time ago" vs absolute time?

Comment: I find this whole situation ironic given the title of your riddle is "Who is the winner?" and now we don't know who the winner is :)

Comment: @Riley oh no, man, you’re right, who’s the winner? Haha, I’ll put Austin as the winner.

Answer (score 7):

The winner is

> Jeremy Reener

because

> The name "The Hardest Riddle Ever Event" has the acronym "THREE". Jeremy Reener was the third guest named in the list. This would explain why people only knew the winner after the announcement, because the announcement contains this clue.

I am somewhat hesitant about my answer because it seems there might be more than one clue hidden in your riddle:

> I am suspicious that the other initials of the contestants, Dr. Doom, and/or "UR" might be relevant. On the other hand, these could just be red herrings so that the "THREE" acronym is less obvious.

Comment: Sorry, wrong man.

Comment: It makes me sad that you got so close but missed. :(